# How to Subscribe to a single Event from multiple classes?

Tags: vb.net, events

I am creating a Draft Room for a football game I am making and have several classes involved with it.

The DraftPick Class will be responsible for raising an Event once the current team has made their selection. However, there are multiple other classes that need to "know" when this event has been fired as well.  The Draft Class needs to know so it can remove the player from the list of available players, restart the clock and update the current team on the clock. The DraftNews Class needs to know about this event so it can update the in-draft ListView with the Pick information, and the DraftTicker class needs to know about the event to add the selection that was just made to the scrolling draft ticker at the bottom of the screen.

I'm working in VB.Net, so its not as straightforward as it would be in C#.  However, I am thinking the easiest way would be to make the PickMade Event shared so the other classes would be able to simply access the event via `DraftPick.PickMade()` and simply use an `AddHandler`.  I was wondering if there is an established "method" for doing this, or if what I am considering doing would be OK.

Any advice would be appreciated, first time I've had the need for multiple classes to be listening to an event...

Comment: It is exactly as straightforward in VB as it is in C#.  Where you would use '+=' in C# to handle an event of an object, you use `AddHandler` in VB.  The two are exactly equivalent.

Comment: OK, thanks for that.  So would the way I'm planning on doing it work properly, or is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: As far as which objects handle the event, I sounds OK based on my limited knowledge of your project. I'm not sure about declaring the event `Shared` though. If you're creating an instance of the `DraftPick` class then the event should be an instance member.  If there are multiple instances then a `Shared` event won't really work and if there aren't multiple instances and you think a `Shared` method is a good idea then the class should probably be a singleton.

Comment: Couldn't I just make the DraftPick Class NotInheritable (Sealed in C#)?  There will only be one instance of the class.

Comment: There's no relationship there. `NotInheritable`/`sealed` means that you cannot declare a derived class. It has no bearing on how many instances of the class itself you can create. If there's only going to be one instance of the class then it should be a singleton and your event should not be `Shared`.  That doesn't mean that it's difficult to access the event though.  The whole point of a singleton class is that it provides a `Shared` property that exposes the one and only instance, so you can access it that instance everywhere and therefore any instance member anywhere.

Comment: My mistake, I meant Abstract or MustInherit meaning a new instance of this class cannot be instantiated

Comment: That would be an abuse.  The point of `MustInherit`/`abstract` is to define a class whose sole purpose is to act as a base class for other types.  Why not just do the right thing?  If you don't want to create any instances of a type then use a static class in C# or a module in VB.  If you want to create a single instance then implement the singleton pattern in either language.